# Bulk update Spring JPA Repositories (Java)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In spring I can define search and delete operations with by defining "Query methods as function names"

So I can do this without writing any logic(sql):

```
List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);
List<Person> deleteByLastName(@Param("name") String name);
```

But how can I bulk update entries without(!) writing sql? This doesn't work:

```
List<Person> updateByLastName(@Param("name") String name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you expecting that updateByLastName to do? Update every lastName to name? There is just not enough information for Spring to figure it out. You need to use JPQL here.

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query( "UPDATE Person p" +
        " SET p.age = :age " +
        " WHERE p.lastName = :lastName" )
List<Person> updateByLastName(@Param("age") int age, @Param("lastName") String lastName);
```

Comment: No! I can update a single entry by sending a http put with a rest body. I'd like to do this also as a bulk update for many entries.

Comment: Ok. Well you can't do that by deriving the query from the method name directly...

Comment: Add your service code where you perform a single update and I'll modify it to provide a bulk (less efficient) update.